# Couldn't make Prev QTR work when the slicer is selected

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I am not able to display Prev QTR measure, when one quarter is selected. If I select 2 quarters this is working. The formula is in below screenshot. Please help

[image: Screenshot]

This is the formula I tried:

```
    Prev QTR =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('fact'[amount_reporting_currency]),
        DATESQTD(
            DATEADD(
            'Dates'[date_id],
            -1,
            QUARTER)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Your expression looks okay. You could also re-write it to: `Prev QTR = CALCULATE([Current QTD], DATEADD('Dates'[date_id], -1, QUARTER))`. Not sure why it isn't working for you. Could it be your are at the earliest quarter? Create a new matrix for  testing, add Year, Quarter in the Rows, and Current QTD and Prev QTR as values.